# How to select item from dropdown menu in Gmail (Selenium WebDriver)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail, automated-tests

I'm getting into automation and right now experimenting with Gmail. When I clicked on the `Drafts` section and then tried to click on the checkbox selector, my script failed with a `WebDriverException`. So far I've only been using a `WebDriver` object called `driver` and used `driver.findElement(...).click()` or `.sendKeys()`. I got the hang of automating button clicks, typing in text fields, and triggering a keyboard key click, and would like to take it to the next level with dropdown menus.

I'm not familiar with other commands so I was hoping someone could help me understand how to click on the email Select checkbox (square box) in Gmail after clicking Drafts and click on the Unread dropdown menu option. When I used Chrome's inspect element feature, I noticed that the class name of the element changes when the cursor hovers over the button that triggers the checkbox under it.

So you can try it out yourself under your Gmail account and see how the class name is different when cursor is on it and when the dropdown menu is triggered. How would you automate the action of clicking on that dropdown menu and clicking the Unread option if the class name dynamically changes like that? I hope I made my issue clear, but let me know if I forgot to mention something.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally a `click()` shall work for the checkboxes.

Following works for me (selects the first mail checkbox in the mailbox) after inspecting the elements and getting the class details from it using FireFox -

```
List<WebElement> emailCheckBox = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".oZ-jc.T-Jo.J-J5-Ji"));
emailCheckBox.get(0).click();
```

---

Try sending `Space` key if its in Internet Explorer

```
emailCheckBox.get(0).sendKeys(Keys.Space);
```